# Syntax to create "instead of insert" trigger in HANA DB

Tags: hibernate, hana

> I am using this syntax

```
CREATE TRIGGER tgBook 
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON "SYSTEM"."BOOK"
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO "SYSTEM"."CLASSA" (rollNo, name, percentage)
SELECT rollNo, name, percentage
FROM INSERTED
INSERT INTO "SYSTEM"."ClassB" (english, maths)
SELECT english, maths
FROM INSERTED
END
```

> I am getting this error

```
Could not execute 'CREATE TRIGGER tgBook INSTEAD OF INSERT ON "SYSTEM"."BOOK" FOR EACH ROW BEGIN INSERT INTO ...'
SAP DBTech JDBC: [257]: sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "INTO": line 8 col 8 (at pos 206)
```

> I am using HANA DB and in HANA DB normal SQL trigger queries are not
>   working so i need the correct syntax  any suggestions are welcomed
>   Thank you

Comment: No need to shout.

Comment: what do you mean by this

Comment: The subject of your question, before I edited it, was in all caps. This is the equivalent of shouting.

Answer (score 0):

> I got the solution actually the syntax was wrong .The actual syntax is

```
CREATE TRIGGER "SYSTEM"."tgBook" INSTEAD OF INSERT ON "SYSTEM"."BOOK" REFERENCING NEW ROW NEW FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN INSERT 
INTO ClassA (rollNo,
    name,
    percentage) VALUES(:NEW.rollNo,
     :NEW.name,
     :NEW.percentage)
;
 INSERT 
INTO ClassB (rollNo,
    english,
    maths) VALUES(:NEW.rollNo,
     :NEW.english,
     :NEW.maths)
;

END
;
```